# insert css background-image in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

how to replace the `"+"`  and `"-"` sign and replace it with css `background-image`. here is the sample code http://jsfiddle.net/9nxAc/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To make them images, simply change out the variables:

```
    closedSign: '[+]',
    openedSign: '[-]'
```

To..

```
    closedSign: '<img src="link/to/image.jpg" />',
    openedSign: '<img src="link/to/next/image.png" />'
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nxAc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this method:

```
ul.topnav span{
    float:right;
    background-image:url('background.png');
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

By doing so the signs won't be visible.​